# kSQLDB Declaring Key field creates random key on Stream or Table

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm using kSQLDB and creating a stream from a topic, when I declare a `KEY` explicitly I get a random looking value which is not my key.  If I remove the `KEY` keyword, the value I need is actually specified in the `Id` column.

Is this known behavior? It doesn't look right to me.

Sample key and value in `topic`:

```json
# key
1000

# value
{
  "id": 1000,
  "other": "hello"
}
```

ksql Streams:

```sql
-- declare id as the key
CREATE STREAM s1 (id INT KEY, other VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topic', VALUE_FORMAT='json');

-- omit declaring id as the key
CREATE STREAM s2 (id INT, other VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topic', VALUE_FORMAT='json');
```

Selecting from s1 with KEY declared provides the following.  That is not my id of 1000:

```
+-----------+--------+
| id        | other  |
+-----------+--------+
| 825241648 | hello  |
```

Selecting from s2 with KEY not declared provides the following. This IS my id of 1000:

```
+-----------+--------+
| id        | other  |
+-----------+--------+
| 1000      | hello  |
```

I've tried kSQLDB and CLI versions:

1. 0.21.0
2. 0.20.0

Is there something I'm missing here? The id doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

What is the key of the record in your Kafka topic?, How did you publish the record?. In your first sentence you are declaring the id  as  KEY , then KSQL is going to load the id from  the kafka record key, in the second sentence, the id column is loaded from the kafka record value json payload.  May be you are getting the value 825241648 because Kafka is consider the key as int and the internal deserializer is sending trash because is reading other data type.You can use the command PRINT to see the entire Kafka records in your topic, in order to see the keys.

```
PRINT 'topic' FROM BEGINNING;
```

Remember that a Kafka record contains key and value

```
<KEY="some-key", VALUE= "{"id": 1000,"other": "hello"}">
```

Comment: thanks for taking a stab at it, the key is `1000` as well when I use `kafka-console-consumer` to read from `topic`.   The record was published through Debezium Connector which I chained transforms to pull out the id as the key.  From there I'm building a stream on `topic` and ran into this issue.

 But maybe I've got some weird serialization stuff going on.  I'll try to push up a reproduce-able sample.

Comment: Which key deserializer did you use in your  kafka-console-consumer command?, if you didn't specify anything, then is taking a String deserializer by default. for thar reason you were able to see the 1000.  CREATE STREAM s1 (id VARCHAR KEY, other VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topic', VALUE_FORMAT='json'); Try to run the above command to see the id content.

Comment: Yep you're right, specifying VARCHAR KEY makes it display the proper value.  I would like an INT though. Looks like I've got to do some conversions

Comment: Then you have 3 options . 1. Set up your Kafka connector to send the key in your desired format, 2.  Use  your second query CREATE STREAM s2 (id INT, other VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topic', VALUE_FORMAT='json'); . if you need  to perform other queries you can use ROKWEY  , and the last one is cast your value  CREATE STREAM  s3 AS 
SELECT CAST(id as  INT) as `id`, other as `other`
FROM s1
PARTITION BY  CAST(id as INT)
EMIT CHANGES;    //Where s1 is the stream created using  id VARCHAR key